# Java static binding is making it awkward to implement a Composite

Tags: java, polymorphism, composite

I have a class structure something like this:

```
interface Composite {}

class Leaf implements Composite { public String val; }

class Node implements Composite {
    private Node parent;
    private Composite left;
    private Composite right;

    public void attachLeft(Composite c) {
         left = c;
    }
    public void attachRight(Composite c) {
         right = c;
    } 
    public void attachLeft(Node n) {
         left = n;
         n.parent = this;
    }
    public void attachRight(Node n) {
         right = n;
         n.parent = this;
    }
    public void attachRandomly(Composite c) {
         if ( ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean() ) {
             attachRight(c);
         } else {
             attachLeft(c);
         }
    }
}
```

I have a method that generates a random tree (pseudocode):

```
// build tree
for some number of nodes :
    make newNode
    oldNode = randomly pick an existing node with an empty right/left 
    oldNode.attachRandomly(newNode)

// fill leaves of tree
for each node with empty right/left :
    while node has empty right/left :
        node.attachRandomly(new Leaf)
```

Unfortunately, because of static binding, the attachLeft/Right(Node c) methods never get called by attachRandomly.  (attachRandomly is getting a Composite, so the Composite version of attachLeft/Right always gets called.)  So my parent attribute is never getting set.

Now, I can think of a couple ways to make this work:

1. Remove the Node version of attachLeft/Right and just use instanceof and casting inside of the Composite version
2. Add a Node-specific version of attachRandomly

Option 1 feels yucky (instanceof!  casting!) and option 2 just feels awkward because of the amount of extra code.  Is there no better way to do this so that polymorphism can kick in and help me out here?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You say _"Unfortunately, because of static binding, the attachLeft/Right(Node c) methods never get called by attachRandomly"_, and 1) it is unclear to me what you mean with static binding and how that would apply here, and 2) given the lack of an implementation of `attachRandomly`, the only reason we can provide you for _the attachLeft/Right(Node c) methods never get called by attachRandomly_ is the fact that your code simply doesn't do that.

Comment: And why are you overloading these methods in the first place? Why not simply stick with the override?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Good point, I hadn't even noticed that (might explain the 'static binding' part, but that is yet another assumption).

Comment: 1) I mean that when the calls to attachLeft/Right in attachRandomly are made, the Composite version of the overloaded method is used rather than the Node version, even when c is a Node; 2) I've updated my code in the question; 3) There is nothing to override.  The Composite interface is just there so we can put either of Leaf or Node in Node's left & right attributes.  Node is the only place we'll need attachLeft/Rigth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write it like this.  This basic idea is called *double dispatching*.  It introduces a new level of dispatching to each of your method calls, to allow dynamic binding to be used.

```
interface Composite {
    void attachToLeft(Node newParent);
    void attachToRight(Node newParent);
}

class Leaf implements Composite { 
    public String val;
    @Override
    public void attachToLeft(Node newParent) {
        newParent.left = this;
    }
    @Override
    public void attachToRight(Node newParent) {
        newParent.right = this;
    }
}

class Node implements Composite {
    private Node parent;
    private Composite left;
    private Composite right;

    public void attachLeft(Composite c) {
         c.attachToLeft(this);
    }
    public void attachRight(Composite c) {
         c.attachToRight(this);
    } 
    @Override
    public void attachToLeft(Node newParent) {
         this.parent = newParent;
         newParent.left = this;
    }
    @Override
    public void attachToRight(Node newParent) {
         this.parent = newParent;
         newParent.right = this.
    }
}
```

Comment: And actually, if I make Composite an abstract class instead of an interface, then Composite can just have the parent attribute and the attachToLeft/Right methods have a common implementation that can just go in Composite itself—no need for the Overrides